# Any other way to establish communication between components angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have established the following ways to build communication between the components.

1.**@input and @output decorator**(but only limited to parent child)
*for sibling components*

2.**creating a service with getter and setter method**(but limitation is if we refresh the page where we are using the data from the service the data will become empty)

3.using cookies (limitations: if i am saving an array it gets stored in form of strings. sometimes becomes tough to get back the original data type)

4.using localstorage

Is there any other ways to communicate between 2 components except these. i have already used all the above. Suggest me any more ways.

5.I have applied the following way using **subject**. But don't know why i am not getting the output

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessageService {
private subject = new Subject<any>();

sendMessage(message: string) {
this.subject.next({ text: message });
 }

clearMessage() {
 this.subject.next();
}

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
 return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

}

**receiving Component**

```
 import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class detailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

message: any;
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().
                        subscribe(message => {
                          this.message = message;
                          console.log("Message");

console.log(this.message);
});
 }
```

**Sending Component**

```
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

sendMessage(): void {
 // send message to subscribers via observable subject
 this.messageService.sendMessage('Message from alert Component to 
 details Component!');
}

clearMessage(): void {
 // clear message
 this.messageService.clearMessage();
}
}
```

But this code is not working.

Comment: What about state management library https://github.com/ngrx/platform?

Comment: Think you cover almost everything thing noteable next to the localStorage there is a sessionStorage. It's working the same but only bound to a tab instead of the whole browser.

Comment: You can also use EventEmitter in _Service_ and use it in your components to _emit_ and _subscribe_ to it.

Comment: @Swoox , Yes but the last one using services is not working. Help me out in that. thanks

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal Can you give me some example code if possible.

Comment: "But this code is not working" subscribe to service in **ngOnInit**, not in cosntructor. (some time along I made a simple example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrv6hs)

Comment: Thanks.. I have implemented this..

Answer (score 2):

As I know you mention the all 2 ways for the communication between components. Also you can use  router parameters. if you are using routing. But your second arguments limitations can be avoided.

2.creating a service with getter and setter method(but limitation is if we refresh the page where we are using the data from the service the data will become empty)

For not to discard the data after refreshing the child element, you can use BehaviorSubject for emitting data. when you refresh, it will emit the last data that it keeps.

this is the way to do it,

In your service, first import BehaviorSubject

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
```

then inside the service class

```
behaviralSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(['']); 
exampleBehaviralSubject = this.behaviralSubject.asObservable();

setValues(val: any[]) {

     this.behaviralSubject.next(val);

}
```

And in the component which you want to subscribe to this service,

first implement components to OnInit, import your service as testService

then override ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
    testServce.exampleBehaviralSubject.subcribe(
        dataArray => {
            console.log(dataArray)
            // your code goes here 
            }
    )
}
```

your first value Will be [''] empty String array. then use testService.setValues(dataArray) to send data. 
this will send data to all components which are subscribed to the testService, when initializing (or refresh)a component last data in the behaviralSubject will be emitted .

Comment: can you give me some sample code of behavior subject. Because i  have tried subject which is not working , may be i am missing something. it will be a great help. thanks

Comment: No, here also when i am refreshing the page data becomes empty. How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Refreshing a page cannot resolved using this method. u want to keep your data in cookie or local memory for that.(i haven't  done that yet). this method only works when a child component refresh or recreate.but not for app refresh.

Comment: like input and output decorator when we refresh the data receiving component, the transferred data remains as it is. Like wise if i will refresh the component where i am subscribing  the subject, i want my data to be there as it is. is it possible?

Comment: where do you provide this service in root or other module?

Comment: providedIn: 'root'

Comment: If provide in root service is singleton so this should work. behaviralSubject emmit last data it has.

Answer (score 2):

> Any other way to establish communication between components

Using a tool for managing application state.

In Angular, the most famous one is NgRx: https://github.com/ngrx/platform .

An alternative for NgRx is Akita which is quite new to Angular developer: https://github.com/datorama/akita

These library is mostly inspired by Redux - which is very famous in the ReactJS world.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EventEmitter in Service and use it in your components to emit and subscribe to it.

Declare your EventEmitter in messaging.service.ts

```
@Injectable(){
export class MessagingService{

    message : EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();

}
```

Use this EventEmitter to emit in your sending component

sending.component.ts

```
export class SendingComponent implements OnInit(){
    constructor(private mService : MessageService) {}
    ngOnInit(){
      this.mService.message.emit('This is my message');
    }
}
```

Use this EventEmitter to subscribe in your receiving components

```
 export class ReceiveComponent implements OnInit(){
    constructor(private mService : MessageService) {}
    ngOnInit(){
      this.mService.message.subscribe(message=>{ console.log(message) });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a state management library. I highly recommend Akita. It's simple and comes with everything you need out of the box, for example, entity store, dev-tools, plugins and more. Check it out:

https://github.com/datorama/akita